# error while using parfor in matlab

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I am using parfor to parallelize a loop in matlab. The code is given below

```
   parfor i = 1:15

   tmp{i,1} = theta(i) * Fw{i,1}' * var1 * Wi{i,1} * var2 * Fw{i,1} ;

   end
```

FW, Wi are cells containing matrices. var1, var2 are matrices. Theta is a vector.

when I execute this code matlab hangs forever, after a long time when I terminate the code it shows the following error.

Warning: Error occurred while evaluating listener callback.

> In main at 58 
>   Error using main (line 58)

Caused by:
    Error using distcomp.remoteparfor/getCompleteIntervals

when I execute the code without parfor ,it works fine.

the full code is given below

```
Fw = cell(15,1);

Wi = cell(15,1);

tmp = cell(15,1);

for i  = 1 : 15
  Fw{i,1} = randn(25344);
  Wi{i,1} = randn(12672);
  theta(i) = 10;
end

var1 = randn(25344,12672);
var2 = randn(12672,25344);
parfor i = 1:15

   tmp{i,1} = theta(i) * Fw{i,1}' * var1 * Wi{i,1} * var2 * Fw{i,1} ;

end
```

Comment: That method is where I would expect your client to block waiting for results to come back from the workers. Do you have reproduction steps that we can try? What version of MATLAB are you running? What cluster type are you using? How large a matlabpool did you open?

Comment: the matlab version I am using is 8.2.0.701 (R2013b). Matlabpool contains 12 workers

Comment: Ok. Do you have a reproduction that we can try?

Comment: can you just clarify what do you mean by reproduction?

Comment: Some code that we can actually run that reproduces the problem. http://sscce.org/

Comment: I have edited my post and pasted the full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PARFOR is designed to operate both on a single machine, and across clusters of machines, and the worker processes do not share an address space. Therefore all data must be copied to the workers. In your case, you are making enormous amounts of data to copy to each of 12 workers. I strongly suspect that the problem you are observing is as a result of the overheads of data transfer, and the fact that each worker needs to store its own copy of `var1` and `var2`.

I would try: starting with a much smaller size for your arrays, and check that things work. As you gradually increase the size, you will probably find a point where things start to go wrong as your machine runs out of memory.

It might help to store `var1` and `var2` in a [sharedmatrix](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28572-sharedmatrix).

Comment: `var1` + `var2` is 5GB - and you've got 13 copies of each (host + 12 workers), which is 65GB. Unfortunately, additional copies are made during transfer, plus you've got the elements of `Fw` and `Wi` to transfer. Did you try reducing the size?

Comment: it is working for matrices of small size. Is there anyway how to make it work for large matrices

Comment: As per my answer, I would try using the sharedmatrix for the constant data - `var1` and `var2`.

Comment: is there any way to do multithread programming directly in matlab script , without writing a MEX File.

Comment: Various intrinsic operations in MATLAB are transparently multithreaded. So for example `rand(1000)*rand(1000)` will use multithreading. But that's probably not what you mean - there's no way in a single MATLAB process to have multiple threads of execution executing different lines of MATLAB code - there's only a single interpreter.